# What is a good one-stop-shop for understanding software licensing information?

Tags: licensing, freelancing

I've learned a fair amount about the various different software licensing models and what those models mean for my own software project. However, I'd like to make sure I understand as many of them as possible for making decisions on how to license my own software and in what scenarios I can safely use software under a licensing model.

Do you have a good recommendation for a book/site etc.. that has this information in one location?

Comment: This didn't help?  It's the first hit on a Google search.http://developer.kde.org/documentation/licensing/licenses_summary.html  What about it was confusing or incomplete?

Comment: Are you saying you didn't search?

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for being such a helpful member of the community.

Comment: @Macy Abbey: I'm asking a question, trying to understand your background on this topic.  Refusing to answer makes it hard to provide an answer that's anything other than random.

Comment: @S.Lott If someone posts here, it's a fairly safe assumption that searching didn't yield a useful answer - it takes much longer to log on, write up a question, and post it, than to try a search.

Comment: @blueberryfields: "searching didn't yield a useful answer".  Agreed.  What was wrong with the answers turned up by search?  What's the gap that needs to be filled?

Comment: @S.Lott - What you see as your first search result might not have been what she sees as her first search result.  Location does play a part in what Google returns.  Although, It's unlikely that's the case as you're both in the United States...

Comment: Also, what you've searched for before will play a role depending on settings.

Comment: Are you looking for Free Software/Open Source licenses only, or proprietary/closed source also?  The Free/Open Source communities are generally helpful about licensing, but I don't know of anything comparable for proprietary/closed source licenses, which anyway tend to be individually written and using specific legal advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also find this site helpful:

http://www.opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical

There is a lot more on this site than on the other link posted.

However, all of this is for open source licenses. If you want to know more about software licenses in general, or for the legal ins and outs of commercial licenses then that is a very different matter. You need a lawyer for that. And a big bucket of money.

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding some grey areas, you may do well to talk to an IP lawyer.  Yes, that will cost money, but sometimes that can be money well spent.